# Altering tablespace for partitioned table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, tablespace

In my database i have a partitioned table with name 'record_partitioned' on PostgreSQL 11.2. 
i want to change its tablespace to a new tablespace 'fast_ssd' so all new dervied tables from this table be in 'fast_ssd' tablespace.

when i try to alter tablespace to 'fast_ssd'.

```
alter table record_partitioned set tablespace fast_ssd;
```

i see:

> ALTER TABLE

but it seems nothing happened! i check tablespace like this:

```
SELECT tablespace,tablename FROM pg_tables where tablename='record_partitioned';
```

and output is:

```
 tablespace |     tablename
------------+--------------------
            | record_partitioned
```

tablespace  does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this for a partitioned table. You'll have to add an explicit `TABLESPACE` clause whenever you create a partition.

An alternative is to set the `default_tablespace` parameter, but that would affect all other tables too.